How to invert the colors of a font? To create a transparent infill
I have a font that I want to invert. I want the background of the characters to be black and the infill to be transparent. The goal is to reveal an animated background through the characters.
Both the characters and the background are dynamic and change at runtime.
Example of a font I want to invert:

Inverted in paint:

An example background:

The desired result:

How do I achieve this? I preferably want to use font forge.
Edit:
in birdfont I can simply draw a rectangle around a glyph and it inverts it. In Inkscape I can draw a rectangle and use the difference tool to invert. But would like to know how to do it in fontforge.

Edit: This answer was posted before the OP mentioned the need for dynamic lettering. I'm leaving it here for referrence. I also note in the comments below that this could be used to create an SVG which could techincally be edited dynamically anyway.
There's no need to actually edit a font for something as simple as this. It's way over complicating things.
Use a vector image editor, such as Inkscape (which is free and open source). This could also be done in other vector software such as Illustrator, Affinity Designer, etc.
Here are the basic steps:

Draw a circle and set the fill to black

Type some text

Apply a gradient fill to the text, edit the gradient as you like (in the screen capture linked below I have already prepared a gradient fill)

Apply a thin white stroke to the text

Drag the text over the top of the black circle, resize/reposition as required


See Screen capture here. Sorry, the file is too big to post here.
If you really need to cut out the letters as negative space it would also be easy to do this by using the Shape Builder tool.  Select the text and circle, and click on the inside of the circle. Then drag the shape over an image or something filled with a gradient


I clarified my question. The digits are changing dynamically. I could export 10 images, one for each digit, and map each character to an image. But using a font for that is cleaner in my opinion.

@elechris You should have mentioned that before. But in any case, there is no need to export raster images.  Inkscape is a vector image editor. It can create SVGs. In the first method I detailed above, the text in the SVG could be edited dynamically.  SVG is just a a kind of XML.

@elechris Here's an example SVG file generated by Inkscape. The link will expire in 24 hours. Download it, and view the SVG in a browser, and zoom in. You will see how clean it is - no pixels! Open the file in a text editor, and find the number 32 near the bottom within the  tag, change it, save it. Refresh your browser.
